# Point on the graph of $y=\sqrt{4x+13}$ closest to $(5,0)$?

Tags: derivatives

Just did this question on an exam earlier today, I'm curious to see if I'm correct.

> What point on the graph of $y=\sqrt{4x+13}$ is closest to $(5,0)$?

My answer: $(-1,3)$

Comment: How did you get that answer?  What did you do to arrive at that conclusion?

Comment: The exam provided a formula for the distance between two points: d=sqrt[(x2-x1)^2+(y2-y1)^2]. I made the x2 and y2 values 5 and 0 respectively. x1 remained x1, and y1 was the formula of the graph. I differentiated the d formula and found a minimum x1 value (-1). Then I solved for y1 and got 3.

Comment: Thanks for the edit yoknapaptawpha, I'm wasn't sure how to format my question properly.

Comment: If I just fill in $x = 5$ I get $y = \sqrt{33} < 6$, i.e. the point $(5,\sqrt{33})$ is also on the curve and has distance less than $6$ to $(5,0)$. Your point has distance more than $6$ to $(5,0)$, so you probably made a mistake in your derivative somewhere.

Comment: It seems that I messed up my derivative....

Comment: @user81942: A [related problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/384410/application-of-derivative-helicopter-problem).

Answer (score 2):

Your method described in the comments seems correct. You start by noting that the distance between $(x,y(x))$ and $(5,0)$ is given by
$$d(x) = \sqrt{(5 - x)^2 + (0 - y(x))^2} = \sqrt{(5 - x)^2 + 4x + 13} = \sqrt{x^2 - 6x + 38}. \tag{1}$$
You want to minimize $d(x)$, so indeed you want to look at the derivative:
$$d'(x) = \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{x^2 - 6x + 38}} \cdot (2x - 6) = \frac{x - 3}{\sqrt{x^2 - 6x + 38}}$$
Solving $d'(x) = 0$ for $x$ we find $x = 3$, and this is indeed a global minimum; this could be proved by showing that $d''(3) > 0$.

So in the end we find a minimum at $(3, \sqrt{4\cdot3+13}) = (3,5)$, and this point has distance $d(x) = \sqrt{3^2 - 6\cdot 3 + 38} = \sqrt{29}$ from $(5,0)$.

---

In this case you can take a shortcut from $(1)$ to the solution as noted by Arthur, by noting that 
$$d(x)^2 = x^2 - 6x + 38 = (x - 3)^2 + 29 \geq 29$$
where the inequality follows from $(x-3)^2 \geq 0$, and equality holds only if $x - 3 = 0$, i.e. if $x = 3$.

Comment: It is even easier to note that the distance squared equals $x^2 - 6x + 38 = (x-3)^2 + 29$.

Comment: @Arthur Ah yes, I missed that one. Then you immediately get that $d(x) \geq \sqrt{29}$ with equality if and only if $x = 3$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $P = (x,\sqrt{4x+13})$ be a generic point of your function, and pose $Q=(5,0)$.
We want to find the point $P$ such that the distance between $P$ and $Q$ is minimal. The distance is:

$$d(x) = \sqrt{(x-5)^2 + \left(\sqrt{4x+13} - 0 \right)^2} = $$
$$= \sqrt{(x-5)^2 + |4x+13|} $$

Minimize the distance is equivalent to minimize the square of the distance. That is:

$$f(x) = d^2(x) = (x-5)^2 + |4x+13| $$

Let's take the derivative of $f(x)$ (note that you have to take care about the absolute value!!!):

$$f'(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{lr}2x - 10 + 4 & x \geq -\frac{13}{4}\\2x - 10 - 4 & x < -\frac{13}{4}\end{array}\right. = \left\{ \begin{array}{lr}2x - 6 & x \geq -\frac{13}{4}\\2x - 14 & x < -\frac{13}{4}\end{array}\right.$$

Now, we must pose $f'(x) = 0$, and then:

$$\left. \begin{array}{lr}2x-6 = 0 & x \geq -\frac{13}{4}\\2x-14 = 0 & x < -\frac{13}{4}\end{array}\right. \Rightarrow \left. \begin{array}{lr}x = 3 & x \geq -\frac{13}{4}\\x = 7 & x < -\frac{13}{4}\end{array}\right.$$

Cleary, the second solution is not admissible since $7 > -\frac{13}{4}$. Hence, the only solution is $x=3$ and then the point you are looking for is: 
$$P=(3, \sqrt{12+13}) = (3, 5)$$

Comment: While you are right that $\sqrt{4x + 13}^2 = |4x + 13|$, the case $4x + 13 < 0$ can already be excluded from the start, since then $y(x)$ would not be real. (And I assume this question does not involve complex numbers.)